# How to increase and decrease alternately product quantity every click?

Tags: magento-1.9, script, jquery

I would like to increase or decrease quantity (by 1) alternately every click on *#grouped-items-table-wrapper* of my Grouped Product Page.

I tried to edit catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml and add my jQuery script at the end but doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('#grouped-items-table-wrapper').click($j("#super_group_46").val(+1););
    });
</script>
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Js/jQuery.

Comment: I should post on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, you cant increment via .val()  you need to do something like something.val( something.val()+1)